# Why does this throw a TypeError?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list

There is a task to find a middle of Linked List. Could you please explain why does `fast.next` in `while()` loop throw a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'next')"?

```
const middleNode = (head) => {
    let fast = head
    let slow = head

    if (head !== null) {
        while (fast.next !== null) {
            fast = fast.next.next
            slow = slow.next
        }
    }
    return slow
}
```

Comment: If `fast.next.next` is null, then `fast = fast.next.next` will do `fast = null;`. Then `fast.next !== null` gets an error.

Comment: your loop should check `while (fast && fast.next)`

Comment: And if you do that, you don't need the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a linked list with two nodes: `[1]-[2]`

```
initial:
fast = [1]
slow = [1]

first iteration (fast.next = [2] != null)
fast = fast.next.next = null
slow = slow.next = [2]

second iteration (attempts to check fast.next = (null.next) => raises TypeError)
```

The fix is to change your condition to check both `fast && fast.next`. You can then remove the if check as well.

```
const middleNode = (head) => {
    let fast = head;
    let slow = head;

    while (fast && fast.next) { // fast != null && fast.next != null
        fast = fast.next.next;
        slow = slow.next;
        
    }
    return slow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If fast.next doesn't have a next node fast.next.next will be null therefore on the next iteration when you check

```
fast.next !== null
```

You are trying to access the next propriety on a null object. You could check if fast exist first like this :

```
while (fast!=null && fast.next !== null) {
            fast = fast.next.next
            slow = slow.next
        }
```